# PHP multidimensional array search by value with random sub-level array

Tags: php

Is it possible to search a multidimensional array of unknown depth by value?

For example, with:

```
$data = [
    [
        'uid' => '100',
        'name' => 'MAIN',
        [
            'uid' => '2222',
            'name' => 'SUB_MAIN',
            [
                'uid' => '8524',
                'name' => 'SUB_SUB_MAIN',
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'uid' => '5465',
        'name' => 'MAIN',
    ],
    [
        'uid' => '40489',
        'name' => 'MAIN',
    ]
];
```

I want to find the path to the sub-array where `uid` is `8524`.

With the above array, the result should be: `[0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: This is something like category tree with no limit sub categories. I want to get ID of specific category from my array.

Comment: "uid" is ID. This is demonstrate array, in my case this is not string but integer... It's really important for you?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried (Show us your code)

Comment: @Yoshi, I want to detect if specific ID exist in my array, and if exist - I want to get array key of this element in my array, I edited my question, sorry.

Comment: @Yoshi exactly!

Comment: @PavloP I changed you question quite a bit, please have a look and *rollback* if it's not what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Yoshi thank you. Important is, my array will contain random sub-levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following as a starting point:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

function findPath(array $items, callable $criteria, array $path = []): array {
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        if (!is_array($item)) {
            continue;
        }

        // prepare path to this item
        $pathToHere = array_merge($path, [$key]);

        // if the items fits the criteria
        if ($criteria($item)) {
            // return it's path
            return $pathToHere;
        }

        // otherwise check children
        $pathToChild = findPath($item, $criteria, $pathToHere);

        // and if return value is not empty
        if (count($pathToChild) > 0) {
            // return path to child
            return $pathToChild;
        }
    }

    // base case if no item matches
    return [];
}


$data = [
    [
        'uid' => '5465',
        'name' => 'MAIN',
    ],
    [
        'uid' => '100',
        'name' => 'MAIN',
        [
            'uid' => '2222',
            'name' => 'SUB_MAIN',
            [
                'uid' => '8524',
                'name' => 'SUB_SUB_MAIN',
                [
                    'uid' => 'X',
                    'name' => 'Y',
                ]
            ],
            [
                'uid' => '8524_test',
                'name' => 'SUB_SUB_MAIN_test',
                [
                    'uid' => '8524_test_sub',
                    'name' => 'SUB_SUB_MAIN_test_sub',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'uid' => '40489',
        'name' => 'MAIN',
    ]
];

$path = findPath($data, fn(array $item): bool => $item['uid'] === '8524_test_sub');

print_r($path);

/*
    Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 0
    )
*/
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/XKTH8

*Note* the code above requires php 7.4, but only because of the `fn() => ...` construct. This could simply be replaced by any other suitable `callable`.